# How do I overwrite image files (in a folder) with one file with command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I'm trying to replace multiple image files with one image file, for the ease of editing my images. I need an automated way of copying over every file (preferably a batch script or using command prompt). I need every file with the extension of .png to be replaced with template.png, *however*, the files need to retain their names.

Comment: provided the template is not ***in*** the current folder, cmd line: `for %P in (*.png) do copy "x:\path\template.png" "%~fP"` In a batch file double the percent signs `%%P`,`%%~fP`

Comment: @LotPings do I run this inside of the folder where the files that I want to replace are stored?

Comment: Yes, either that or provide a path with `y:\path\*.png`

Comment: @LotPings Thanks, that worked a charm, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Type into the command line (at the current directory):

`for %P in (*.png) do copy /Y "t:\he\path\to\the\template.png" "%~fP"`

*Thanks LotPings!*